# AWS python SDK, user is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-bedrock-workshop/blob/main/00_Intro/bedrock_boto3_setup.ipynb) tutorial for using Bedrock from Python and I have difficulties making this piece of code working:

```
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "us-east-1"
#os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = "<YOUR_PROFILE>"
os.environ["BEDROCK_ASSUME_ROLE"] = "arn:aws:iam::028367089014:role/ChaterRole"  # E.g. "arn:aws:..."


boto3_bedrock = bedrock.get_bedrock_client(
    assumed_role=os.environ.get("BEDROCK_ASSUME_ROLE", None),
    region=os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", None),
    runtime=False
)
```

- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION I think I got this one correct, I set it to "us-east-1" since this is the first part of the url when I access AWS console (https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com)
- AWS_PROFILE I commented it out because whatever value I set it it brought an error

> botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (789445423131)
> could not be found

- BEDROCK_ASSUME_ROLE I created a role in the AWS console by going to Access Management > Roles and I set its Trusted entities value as "AWS Service: chatbot" (I was not sure about it)

but this code returned me this error:

> botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

So I also added this (don't worry none of credentials here are the real ones):

```
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "748TZERZGFZEFEZGKN"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "B3xxtrfadzadazFxxxj79bGvadezdezd"
```

But I now I get

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when
> calling the AssumeRole operation: User:
> arn:aws:iam::028367088114:user/UserBedRock is not authorized to
> perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:
> arn:aws:iam::028367088114:role/ChaterRole

I am stuck now...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all that Role stuff.

Just store your IAM User credentials by using the `aws configure` command. It will ask you for an Access Key and Secret Key, and they will be placed into the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

Then, the `utils/bedrock.py` file will simply create the client based on those credentials. **Do not** pass any values for `assumed_role`.

The `get_bedrock_client` will then simply create the client using this code:

```py
    bedrock_client = session.client(
        service_name=service_name,
        config=retry_config,
        **client_kwargs
    )
```